# Remove parenthesis in a haskell statement

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, parentheses

I'm trying to a bytestring manipulation using folds and appends. Please see the  code below.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

selectSource :: [String] -> C.ByteString
selectSource xs = C.append (foldl addSource emptySource xs) (C.pack "<head>")
```

`addSource` and `emptySource` are defined accordingly. It looks a bit ugly with the parenthesis and I'd like to remove them in the `selectSource` function  as

```
C.append $ foldl addSource emptySource xs $ C.pack "<head>"
```

but failed to do so and got an error messaging saying

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘C.ByteString -> C.ByteString’
            with actual type ‘C.ByteString’
The first argument of ($) takes one argument,
but its type ‘SourceByteString’ has none
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘foldl addSource emptySource [] $ C.pack "<head>"’
```

This works

```
C.append (foldl addSource emptySource xs) $ C.pack "<head>"
```

but it still has one last pair of parenthesis.

Comment: It's ok to have few parenthesis

Comment: Isn't there any way to do it without parenthesis? Its all right if there isn't. I just wanted to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can write this with no parenthesis by using `C.append` as an [infix operator](https://wiki.haskell.org/Infix_operator).

```
selectSource :: [String] -> C.ByteString
selectSource xs = foldl addSource emptySource xs `C.append` C.pack "<head>"
```

Since `ByteString`s have [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid) instances with `mappend = append` you can write this more elegantly with the infix `Monoid` operator [`<>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-).

```
import Data.Monoid

selectSource :: [String] -> C.ByteString
selectSource xs = foldl addSource emptySource xs <> C.pack "<head>"
```

If you enable [`OverloadedStrings`](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/posts/2014-12-17-overloaded-strings.html) you can write string literals like `"<head>"` and use them as `ByteString`s. The `ByteString`'s `fromString` is either `pack` or `packChars` as appropriate (it's `pack` for `Char8` `ByteString`s). This can get rid of one set of parenthesis, which will let you write `selectSource` point-free without any parenthesis.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

selectSource :: [String] -> C.ByteString
selectSource = flip C.append "<head>" . foldl addSource emptySource
```

If you prefer the operator to `flip` you can write this point-free with an [operator section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) instead. This requires parenthesis around the operator for the operator section syntax. Operator section parenthesis don't bother me because I never nest them.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}    
import Data.Monoid

selectSource :: [String] -> C.ByteString
selectSource = (<> "<head>") . foldl addSource emptySource
```

With either point-free definition we can add additional functions like `C.init` without messing around with parenthesis.

```
selectSource' :: [String] -> C.ByteString
selectSource' = flip C.append "<head>" . C.init . foldl addSource emptySource

selectSource' :: [String] -> C.ByteString
selectSource' = (<> "<head>") . C.init . foldl addSource emptySource
```

Comment: I've writing another piece of code which I thought looked a bit ugly `(C.init . foldl addSource emptySource $ xs) <> C.pack "<head>"` . Can you suggest a way to remove this pair of parenthesis?

Comment: @user2512324 I'd use `mconcat [ C.init . foldl addSource emptySource $ xs , C.pack "<head>" ]` which has nicer brackets. Otherwise `C.append` as shown above should work.

Comment: @user2512324 It's easy to add additional functions like that when the definition is written point-free. I've added some point-free examples to my answer.